# TypeError: _this.props.selectFlat is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to use to use the function "selectFlat" to update the "lng" and "lat" of the selectedFlat. So i transfered the function by a props.

In the class Flat, I use handleClick function, to trigger this function i get this error.

If someone have an advice that would be amazing ! :)

````
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import flats from './flats';
import ListFlats from './list-flat';
import Flat from './flat';
import MapA from './map';


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = ({
      listFlats: flats,

      selectedFlat: {
        lng: 48.884211,
        lat: 2.34689
      }
    });
  }

  selectFlat = (lng, lat) => {
    this.setState({ selectedFlat: { lng: lng, lat: lat } });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="flat-list">
          <ListFlats listFlats={this.state.listFlats} selectFlat={this.selectFlat} />
        </div>
        <div className="map-container">
          <MapA selectedFlat={this.state.selectedFlat} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Flat extends Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.selectFlat(this.props.lng, this.props.lat);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="card" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${this.props.imageUrl})`}}
        onClick={this.handleClick} onKeyDown={this.handleClick}
      >
        <div className="card-category">{this.props.price}</div>
        <div className="card-description">
          <h2>{this.props.name}</h2>
        </div>
        <a className="card-link" href="#"></a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Flat;
```
````

Comment: add your `ListFlats` component code as well. Where you are using `selectFlat` in this component?

Answer (score -1):

You need to bind selectFlat: under the state or the super declaration, add

```
this.selectFlat = this.selectFlat.bind(this);
```

Comment: If you write the function like this `selectFlat = (lng, lat) => {}`. You don't need to manually bind this. It auto binds the function.